# Excel: Insert Formula Across Multiple Worksheets With Different End Points

Tags: excel, match, drag

I have a file with 300 worksheets in which I need to insert a formula (`INDEX/MATCH`) in Column G of each worksheet.  Each worksheet has a different end point, for example, Worksheet1 ends on row 30, Worksheet2 ends on row 600, Worksheet3 ends on row 44 etc.

The formula I enter will be on cell G2 across all 300 worksheets but each worksheet will have a different ending row.  I want to enter the `INDEX/MATCH` formula on cell G2, but have it end at the last row for each tab.  Trying to avoid dragging the formula down and then going to each tab to remove rows that are not needed.

Comment: Does your setup preclude using full-column references instead of two to the last row?

Comment: I think BigBen is referring to the fact that you can set your Match() formula to match ALL of column G, like Match("XYZZY", $G:$G,0). and then you don't need to shorten the range.